# Macro function pointer issue

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have been working on writing a few preprocessor macros in **C** to help me with my work.

```
            # define    printSTRING(s) printf( # s " has the value");   \
                        for( ; *s != '\0'; s++) \
                        printf(*s); \
                        getch();
```

I am getting the error: `C2105: '++' needs l-value`

when I call `printSTRING(Payload);` where `Payload` is `char Payload[] = "wjdoidnjdeioejneiodejndo";`

I take it that its not seeing `Payload` as a char pointer, but I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: The preprocessor has no concept of pointers, etc.  It merely substitutes and expands macros.  Figure out what this macro expands to (use the `-E` flag if you're using GCC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not they only error you will get. You probably want to use `putchar()` instead, which takes a single `char` argument (`printf()` takes a `char *` format string, which you're not giving it). Or, you can use `puts()` which prints the whole string (there's no need to write a loop yourself in that case).

The reason you are getting the error is that `Payload` is the name of an *array*, not a pointer. You cannot "increment" an array, although you can use the name of an array as if it were a pointer to the start of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know about the puts function...derp.

Comment: You can to use `putchar()` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/putchar.html) too. It's an alias to: `putc(c, stdout)`

Comment: @Jack: You're quite right, I meant `putchar()` instead of `putch()`. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3):

1. You're abusing printf -- that's why the '%s' format specifier is here.
2. 'Payload' wasn't declared as a char **pointer** but as a char **array** -- you can't modify the address of an array. Use simply

   ```
   #define printSTRING(s) printf("%s has the value %s", #s, s)
   ```

instead.